# ReactJS: already declared in the upper scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have declared a variable like

```
const [listRealm, setListRealm] = useState([
    {
      value: null,
      label: 'select one',
    },
  ]);

  const findList= async () => {
    await axios.get(`${apiUrl}`).then(resp => {
      resp.data.map(res => {
        setListRealm(listRealm => [...listRealm, { value: res.id, label: res.name}]); // error here
      });
    });
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    findList();
  }, []);
```

Now my problem is that I receive error:

> 'listRealm' is already declared in the upper scope  @typescript-eslint/no-shadow

I don't understand how I can change name of variable, considering that i'm setting this variable.

How can I do? thank you

Comment: That's not an error anyway, it's just your linter warning about potentially confusing code.

Comment: You should be able to simplify this so that you're not calling setListRealm multiple times:  `setListItems(lstR => [...lstR, ...resp.data.map(res => ({ value: res.id, label: res.name}))])`, as a side note `.map()` for iteration only is not what map should be used for, instead `.forEach()` can be used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name you use in the `setListRealm` callback can be anything you want, so you can just make it `previousListRealm` or just `previous` or something:

```
setListRealm(previousListRealm => [...previousListRealm, { value: res.id, label: res.name}]);
```

It doesn't have to match the name of the constant you've put the value from `useState` in.

---

A few other suggestions:

1. As [Nick pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69851793/reactjs-already-declared-in-the-upper-scope/69851866#comment123474363_69851793), you'd be better off doing your `map` first, and then adding all the elements to state at the same time. (And separately, please see my post [*Misusing `map`*](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/) — `map` isn't the right tool if you're not using the array it returns.)
2. Your `findList` is an `async` function. In general, it's best to avoid mising `async`/`await` with explicit promise methods like `then`. Just use `await` without using `then`.
3. The code calling `findList` needs to handle the fact it may reject its promise.
4. There's no need to re-create the `findList` function on every render if you only use it on the first render.
5. There's no point to the template literal in `` axios.get(`${apiUrl}`) ``, just use `axios.get(apiUrl)`.

So for example:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const findList = async () => {
        const { data } = await axios.get(apiUrl);
        const additions = data.map(({ id, name }) => ({ value: id, label: name }));
        setListRealm((previous) => [...previous, ...additions]);
    };
    findList()
    .catch((error) => {
        // ...handle.report error...
    });
}, []);
```

Or don't use an extra function at all:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(apiUrl)
    .then(({data}) => {
        const additions = data.map(({ id, name }) => ({ value: id, label: name }));
        setListRealm((previous) => [...previous, ...additions]);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // ...handle.report error...
    });
}, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

setListRealm(listRealm <--  You can name it here.